# How can I print data that I filtered out of my mysql table?

Tags: java, mysql

I am currently developing a school project and once again require some advice from fellow coders. I basically have a mysql table from which I filter out data (according to conditions). I used to print this filtered data to the console, however I now want to go further and want to print the results (real life printing).

Is there a simple way to maybe write the data to another table and print it?
If not is there perhaps a way to just export the data (maybe in the form of a txt.file)?

My problem is basically that I am still a beginner who doesn't know most of the Java terms and functions. It would therefore be very helpful if someone could perhaps recommend a simple way to fulfil the above requirements.

Comment: Since you can access data next step is googling 'java fileoutputstream tutorial' or 'java filewriter example' keywords

Comment: are you trying to write java programme which prints data from one table to another?

Comment: What is the difference between "print to the console" which you already did, and "print the result (real life printing)"?

Comment: You can write your data to any file using File IO APIs and also you can create excel sheet by using Apache-POI

Comment: You can export generated data in csv file and then from csv file you can print it.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: For the future, make sure you look at google a bit before you go straight to asking. Stackoverflow is a great resource, but you can't rely upon asking questions for everything. A lot of programming requires you to go and do research. Try and save it for a last resort.

You can insert the values into a new table like this:

```
// create a Statement from the connection
Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

// insert the data
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO yourDataTable " + "VALUES (whatever you want)");
```

or for the txt file option you can do system.io:

```
FileWriter yourFile = new FileWriter("out.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    yourFile.write("something");
}

yourFile.close();
```

The first one is probably easier and will look better.